# Select records for a certain year Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have an oracle table that store transaction and a date column. If I need to select records for one year say 2013 I do Like this:

```
select * 
  from sales_table
 where tran_date >= '01-JAN-2013'
   and tran_date <= '31-DEC-2013'
```

But I need a Straight-forward way of selecting records for one year say pass the Parameter '2013' from an Application to get results from records in that one year without giving a range. Is this Possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use **to_date** function

http://psoug.org/reference/date_func.html

```
select *
  from sales_table
 where tran_date >= to_date('1.1.' || 2013, 'DD.MM.YYYY') and 
       tran_date < to_date('1.1.' || (2013 + 1), 'DD.MM.YYYY')
```

solution with explicit comparisons `(tran_date >= ... and tran_date < ...)` is able to *use index(es)* on `tran_date` field.

Think on *borders*: e.g. if `tran_date = '31.12.2013 18:24:45.155'` than your code `tran_date <='31-DEC-2013'` will *miss* it

Comment: I think you are right. I have actually Missed these out several times.

Answer (score 43):

Use the [extract](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm) function to pull the year from the date:

```
select * from sales_table
where extract(YEAR from tran_date) = 2013
```

Comment: If `tran_date` is indexed, would this use of EXTRACT force a Table Scan, or could Oracle translate this into a Range Seek? *(The equivalent methods in other SQL dialects would normally yield a Scan, which can cause thus to be horrendously inefficient.)*

Comment: Thanks I tried also with DAY and MONTH and found out I can do the same thing.

Comment: Does this Mean if the date Field is indexed then I am doomed? :)

Comment: Technically you can create (in Oracle) index on function (on exract(year ...) in this case): http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/8i/function-based-indexes.php

Answer (score 1):

```
select last_name,hire_date 
from employees
where extract(year from hire_date) = 2006;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select FIRST_NAME , to_char(hire_date, 'YYYY') YR FROM employees where to_char(hire_date, 'YYYY')= '2006'
```

Comment: Hello, this is a bad solution. Please do not use date to string conversion. Preferable solution is extract.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table_name where YEAR(date_column_name) = 2019
```

Comment: Please explain your answer with a few words. What does it do, how does it differeciate from the other answers?